# Moving a Player around a Board with User Input: "Left dx Up dy"

Tags: python, 2d, coordinates, game-development

I've made a grid using the following code:

```
board = []
x = choice_size
y = x
for row in range(0,x):
    board.append(["()"]*y)

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print(" ".join(row))

print_board(board)
```

I need to give the user options to enter input (e.g `"Left 10 Up 2"`) and then move them to the corresponding position on the board.

I've tried messing about with adding their numbers to variables to then get the x and y position in the list `board` but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: `board[y][x] = "Hello World!"`

Comment: @furas what do you mean by this?

Comment: if you need user in place `(x,y)` then use `board[y][x] = "user_symbol"`.

Comment: in console can be problem with clearing screen to redraw board and with getting key/mouse event. Maybe see [urwid](http://urwid.org/) or `ncurses` module

Comment: @furas Thanks, so the "y" is the position of the sublist within the list and the "x" is the position in that sublist?

Comment: yes, `y` means sublist, `x` means element in this sublist. Maybe it's better to use names `row`, `col` then there is no problem with understanding `board[row][col]`

Answer (score 1):

This is example how to move player on board

But it uses Linux special symbol to clear terminal/console before redrawing board.

```
import time

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE names)

SIZE_X = 10
SIZE_Y = 5

SYMBOL_EMPTY  = '( )'
SYMBOL_PLAYER = '(@)'
#SYMBOL_DANGER = '(!)'

# --- functions --- (lower_case names)

def print_board(board):
    print('\33c') # clear terminal on Linux

    for row in board:
        print("".join(row))


def move_player(new_x, new_y):
    global player_x
    global player_y

    # remove in old place
    board[player_y][player_x] = SYMBOL_EMPTY

    # put in new place
    player_x = new_x
    player_y = new_y
    board[player_y][player_x] = SYMBOL_PLAYER

# --- main --- (lower_case names)

# creat board

board = [ ]

for row in range(SIZE_Y):
    board.append([SYMBOL_EMPTY] * SIZE_X)

# display empty board

print_board(board)
time.sleep(0.5)

# set player position and symbol

player_x = player_y = 0

board[player_y][player_x] = SYMBOL_PLAYER

# display board with player    

print_board(board)
time.sleep(0.5)

# move player

# move left
for new_x in range(SIZE_X):
    move_player(new_x, player_y)

    # redraw
    print_board(board)
    time.sleep(0.5)

# move down
for new_y in range(SIZE_Y):
    move_player(player_x, new_y)

    # redraw
    print_board(board)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Real program can be more complex.

In console can be problem with clearing screen to redraw board and with getting key/mouse event to make it real interactive. Maybe see [urwid](http://urwid.org/) or `ncurses` module.

Or try graphic modules like [PyGame](http://pygame.org/docs/), [Pyglet](http://pyglet.readthedocs.io/)

Answer (score 1):

Try thinking about changing the x/y value by adding or subtracting a number, depending on which direction the player wants to move.